# Put image as an object into state variable and pass it as a props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to put an image as an object into state and pass the state as a props in react but it's not passing anything.

```
import xaprikaScreen from "./images/xaprikaScreenShot.jpg";
import linguadenScreen from "./images/linguadenScreenShot.jpg";

export class Portfolio extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      currentProject: 0,
      projects: [
        {
          id: 1,
          projectName: "Linguaden.com",
          projectLink: "www.linguaden.com",
          githubLink: "",
          displayPicture: { linguadenScreen },
          projectDescription: ""
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          projectName: "Xaprika.com",
          projectLink: "www.Xaprika.com",
          githubLink: "",
          displayPicture: { xaprikaScreen },
          projectDescription: ""
        }
      ]
    };
  }

render() {
    return (
    <Projects imageSource={this.state.projects[this.state.currentProject["displayPicture"]}/>
);
}
}
}
```

Here i have imported 2 images as an object, then i have assigned them into state and then i am trying to pass those variables as props.

Comment: `Projects`' `imageSource` prop should be receiving an object with a `linguadenScreen` property in it, though it's possible that `linguadenScreen`'s value is _undefined_.

Comment: Without a [mcve], we can't help much.

Comment: linguadenScreen is not undefined actually, if pass that object directly as a props then its working fine.

Comment: [Kognise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55325715/1218980) spotted the problem correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're doing `this.state.currentProject["displayPicture"]`. The value of `currentProject` is `0`, and `0.displayPicture` is undefined. You're then doing `this.state.projects[this.state.currentProject["displayPicture"]`, which not only doesn't have a closing bracket, even if it did that would be equivalent to `this.state.projects[undefined]` which is also undefined.

Replace your render function with the below code and it should work.

```
render() {
  return (
    <Projects imageSource={this.state.projects[this.state.currentProject].displayPicture} />
  );
}
```

Comment: Isn't it same ??

Comment: @VictorDeb No, it isn't. Read my explanation

Comment: @VictorDeb You're missing a closing bracket in your code. `projects[currentProject]['displayPicture']` would be the same, but when you know the property name, it's best to use the dot notation.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Funny, I interpreted as the closing bracket being missing somewhere else lol! `this.state.projects[this.state.currentProject["displayPicture"]HERE`. I see what you mean, though.

Comment: this.state.projects[this.state.currentProject].displayPicture this not working

Comment: @VictorDeb and what's the problem? Is there an error?

Comment: nop im facing the same problem as before, the props is showing [object][object]

Comment: @VictorDeb Well, the `displayPicture` is an object. Not sure why you have `{ linguadenScreen }` and `{ xaprikaScreen }`, maybe you meant `linguadenScreen1` and `xaprikaScreen` instead?